# Use C# to save a file in a folder or shared folder in a remote machine. The remote machine is in another domain

Tags: c#, file

I have a C# api hosted on domain A. This api receives files as form-data (I extract the file using HttpContext.Current.Request.Files). In this api, I need to implement a method to save the extracted file to a folder or shared folder in a remote machine that is in another domain say domain B (My company domain). I have the access credentials of the machine running in domain B.

I am using VS2015 for development. My target framework is .NET 4.5.2.
I have tried using WNetUseConnection(Mpr.dll) method to connect. Using this method, I am able to successfully connect and save the files when connecting from the same domain as the remote machine. But when i tried to connect from outside domain B(the remote machine's domain), I am unable to do so. I am getting error 53. I researched about this error and found that it is "network path was not found".

I feel like I'll need all the help I can get. Need to get this done in 2 days.

Given below is my function call to connect to the remote machine in domain B.

```
RemoteConnect.connectToRemote("\\xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx\C$", @"domain-B\username", "password");
```

I have given below the code I have in my connection class (RemoteConnect.cs) for using WNetUseConnection.

```
[DllImport("Mpr.dll")]
        private static extern int WNetUseConnection(
            IntPtr hwndOwner,
            NETRESOURCE lpNetResource,
            string lpPassword,
            string lpUserID,
            int dwFlags,
            string lpAccessName,
            string lpBufferSize,
            string lpResult
        );

        [DllImport("Mpr.dll")]
        private static extern int WNetCancelConnection2(
            string lpName,
            int dwFlags,
            bool fForce
        );

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        private class NETRESOURCE
        {
            public int dwScope = 0;
            public int dwType = 0;
            public int dwDisplayType = 0;
            public int dwUsage = 0;
            public string lpLocalName = "";
            public string lpRemoteName = "";
            public string lpComment = "";
            public string lpProvider = "";
        }


        public static string connectToRemote(string remoteUNC, string username, string password)
        {
            return connectToRemote(remoteUNC, username, password, false);
        }

        public static string connectToRemote(string remoteUNC, string username, string password, bool promptUser)
        {
            NETRESOURCE nr = new NETRESOURCE();
            nr.dwType = RESOURCETYPE_DISK;
            nr.lpRemoteName = remoteUNC;
            //          nr.lpLocalName = "F:";

            int ret;
            if (promptUser)
                ret = WNetUseConnection(IntPtr.Zero, nr, "", "", CONNECT_INTERACTIVE | CONNECT_PROMPT, null, null, null);
            else
                ret = WNetUseConnection(IntPtr.Zero, nr, password, username, 0, null, null, null);

            if (ret == NO_ERROR) return null;
            return getErrorForNumber(ret); 
        }

        public static string disconnectRemote(string remoteUNC)
        {
            int ret = WNetCancelConnection2(remoteUNC, CONNECT_UPDATE_PROFILE, false);
            if (ret == NO_ERROR) return null;
            return getErrorForNumber(ret);
        }
```

Comment: The "c$" only works if you have admin privileges on local and remote machines.  To get access so everybody can access files you need to change privileges on folder/files so everybody has full privileges.  You probably need your MIS people to help.  For testing to prove I'm correct use a Windows Explorer and see if you have access to folder/files on remote machine.  The explorer will emulate what the c# code is doing.

Comment: _from outside domain B_ Are the domains on the same subnet? If not, can you actually see the IP address of the remote server from where you are running the code?  Have you tried to connect to the share manually in Explorer to make sure it's visible? **Error 53: Network path not found** would seem to give a vital clue to the actual problem here.

Comment: @jdweng . When I ran the code from domain B, it worked fine. I was able to create directory and save file.

Comment: @Martin They are not on the same subnet. I cant access the IP of the remote machine without connecting to my company's VPN. I am running this code from my home, to check the connectivity from outside domain B.

Comment: @Martin Just now I connected to company VPN and ran my code from my home. It worked fine. But I need to connect to the remote machine and save files, from outside domain B.

Comment: If you need to connect to remote machines than you MIS people will need to make changes to the credentials of the files to allow changes without a connections.  You may want to put files on a Network Drive that is both accessible on both machines.  I Network drive is on Disk Server that allows the file to be shared by everybody.  It is really no different from any other machine except for the default credentials of the files and folders.  Any Machine can look like a Network drive if the credentials are set properly.

Comment: @jdweng Ok. I will check with the network team about the permissions of 'C$' folder.  Thanks for your response.

Comment: C$ will only work if you have admin on both local and remote machine.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried NetworkCredential? Maybe I'm thinking too simple and am not understanding your problem..

This has always worked for my needs:

```
NetworkCredential networkCredential = new NetworkCredential("username", "password", "domainname");
CredentialCache credentialCache = new CredentialCache();
credentialCache.Add(new Uri(@"\\networkshare\"), "Basic", networkCredential);
//Proceed with whatever file-io you need using the normal .NET file io. Example:
string[] folders = System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories(@"\\networkshare\Users\Userimages");
```